# Routing history with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a route : https://localhost/search/. I have not used search parameter in the routing parameter in the vuejs client side. The request is send to an api endpoint which is sent as search text and page_no as params and it provides me the result .
I watch the parameters of page_no for sending request as we go back and forth on the browser. But the problem is that, when a search text is changed how can I go back from the browser with the particular search text.. I thought of providing search text in front end routing too but I want to avoid that.

Comment: You need to manage your own history by using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API.

Comment: How to manage own history?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you putting the search query in the URL like `/search?q=foo`? If not, why?

Comment: No I dont want the search params to be in url , only in requests url.

Answer (score 2):

When you navigate to new search result, you should call pushState yourself. Since `vue-router` will not push another state if the destination route is same as current. Then you need to handle `onpopstate` event to update your `SearchComponet`.

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
      alert("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
    };

history.pushState({query: "a"}, null);
```

First argument to`pushState` is state object — The state object is a JavaScript object which is associated with the new history entry created by pushState(). Whenever the user navigates to the new state, a popstate event is fired, and the state property of the event contains a copy of the history entry's state object.

Comment: I got the idea, will try it.

Comment: quick question, why can't we access store state in onpopstate?

Comment: Can you show your code. I guess it might be related to `this` https://medium.com/@anjalisharma0626/what-is-call-site-of-a-function-8e5d9881c49e. You can solve this by using an arrow function `window.onpopstate = (event) => { this.$store.state }`.